# ITextSharp - using PdfStamper resulting MemoryStream to close

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, memorystream

I'm using ITextSharp to split multi-page PDF files into single page files. I also managed to add those single page PDFs to a zip file using MemoryStream.

Now, I need to add password protection to those PDFs using PdfStamper, before adding them into a zip file. But whenever I tried this, an `ObjectDisposedException - Cannot access a closed Stream.` is being throwed.

```
Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zipFile = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile();

        int cnt = 0;
        try
        {
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(new iTextSharp.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray(sourcePdfPath), new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(""));

            for (cnt = 1; cnt <= reader.NumberOfPages; cnt++)
            {
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document())
                    {
                        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);

                        using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, memoryStream))
                        {
                            stamper.SetEncryption(
                                null,
                                Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("password_here"),
                                PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING,
                                PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
                        }

                        memoryStreamForZipFile = new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray());
                        memoryStreamForZipFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    }
                }
            }

            zipFile.Save(destinationFolder + "/" + fileName.Replace(".pdf", ".zip"));

            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
        return cnt - 1;
```

*I have removed some codes above for clarity.*

If I'll remove the PdfStamper "using" block, the code works just fine. I also tried to juggle the position of PdfStamper to see if I used it in the wrong place.

Am I not using `using` blocks properly? Or I have to fix some code sequence in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You removed some lines that are essential are wrong; for instance: I assume that you are adding a `PdfImportedPage` to the `PdfContentByte` of a `PdfWriter`. If that's so, you are ignoring all the warnings given in the official documentation.

You should replace your code by something like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pathToFile);
int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
int cnt;
for (cnt = 1; cnt <= reader.NumberOfPages; cnt++)
{
    reader = new PdfReader(pathToFile);
    reader.SelectPages(cnt.ToString());
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, memoryStream))
    {
        stamper.SetEncryption(
            null,
            Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("password_here"),
            PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING,
            PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
    }
    reader.Close();
    // now do something with the memoryStream.ToArray()
}
```

As you can see, there is no need to introduce a `Document` or a `PdfWriter` object. If you use those classes, you throw away all interactivity that exists in the original pages. You also get into trouble if the page size of the original pages is different from A4.

Note that you can't reuse the `PdfReader` instance when using `PdfStamper`. Once you pass a `PdfReader` instance to a `PdfStamper`, that instance is *tampered*.

Comment: This worked. I have one side question though. One of the lines I've removed above is `stamper.SetFullCompression();` after setting the password through `stramper.SetEncryption`. I just noticed that whenever I compress the pdf (in memoryStream), almost the same size is being produced.

Comment: Same thing goes with zipping a pdf. Without setting a password through ITextSharp, the zipped result is compressed significantly. But with a password, almost the same size. Is this intrinsic with pdf or ITextSharp's?

Comment: It is inherent to PDF: encryption results in larger files. The difference between using `setFullCompression()` or not using it, is most apparent in the cross-reference table. You should look at the file in a text editor and compare the part that follows the `xref` keyword.